# iOS 11 getUserMedia not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, webrtc, getusermedia

Apple released a statement that `getUserMedia` will be fully functional on iOS 11. After installing iOS 11 Beta version 5, I do get a message that my website requests access to my camera and microphone, but it seems that the line:

```
video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
```

or:

```
video.srcObject = stream;
```

Does not work. No errors, no exceptions, simply no picture from the phone's camera.

Here's my full script:

```
$(function () {
     video = document.getElementById('vid');

     navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                              navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                              navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

     navigator.getUserMedia(
     {
         audio: true,
         video: { facingMode: "user" }
     }, function (stream) {
         video.srcObject = stream;
         //video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
     },
     function (err) {           
         alert(err.name);
     });
});
```

HTML:

```
<video id="vid" muted autoplay></video>
```

Has anyone got it working? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Solved it by using the following:

```
$(function () {
    video = document.getElementById('vid');
    video.style.width = document.width + 'px';
    video.style.height = document.height + 'px';
    video.setAttribute('autoplay', '');
    video.setAttribute('muted', '');
    video.setAttribute('playsinline', '');

    var constraints = {
         audio: false,
         video: {
             facingMode: 'user'
         }
    }

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function success(stream) {
        video.srcObject = stream;
    });
});
```

Comment: Yep, it's moved to navigator.mediaDevices. Also note that while video seems to work everywhere, audio doesn't work on iPod touch - asking for audio causes an Overconstrained Error.

Comment: I got a black screen in video and I have almost the same code. did you face this problem ? thanks

Comment: SOLVED black screen :  <video id="videoforsaf" autoplay playsinline></video>

Comment: I'm keep getting same issue like described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46981889/how-to-resolve-ios-11-safari-getusermedia-invalid-constraint-issue

Although I'm running iOS11.1

Comment: @IvanPandžić I'll be happy to help if you post a new question with your code and link it to me here as a comment. Voting up my question and asnwer would be appreciated too :)

Comment: in my case helped `constraints  {audio: false, video: {height: 720,width:1280,facingMode: "environment",frameRate: {max:30}}}` iphone requeres,  resolution empty for ipad

Comment: Wait, so what's the fix here? Is it that you moved from `navigator.getUserMedia` to `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` or that you converted it from callbacks to promises? Or the styling/attributes, or what? Coz none of that's working for me :(

Comment: @KobyDouek Here's my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70078568/6048715 . I upvoted your question but your answer doesn't work for me so I can't upvote it :P