# iOS 11 Public beta 5 getUserMedia not working

Tags: getusermedia, ios11

I'm trying to experiment with the getUserMedia API that should be enabled in the ios11 beta as this questions seems to suggest: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45692526/ios-11-getusermedia-not-working)

I'm trying to setup the same on my iPad with the latest public beta (5) but I can't get it to work. The error I get is:

> NotAllowedError (DOM Exception 35): The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.

A popup that asked for permission never appears so I didn't deny this, I don't know what is going wrong. I tried enabling/disabling the experimental feature 'Remove Legacy WebRTC API' in the browser settings, but this has no effect either.

Do I need the developer beta to access this feature?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getUserMedia requires HTTPS unless you use the "allow media capture on insecure sites" shown in the [first screenshot of this webkit blog post](https://webkit.org/blog/7763/a-closer-look-into-webrtc/)

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting this error on Safari. iOS11 stops autoplay audio and Chrome will do the same in January, 2018.

**How to enable autoplay on Safari?**
- Go to Safari > Preferences > Auto-Play
- Instead of "Stop Media with Sound", pick "Allow all Auto-Play" option for your website and try again. The error will not pop-up on your machine.

**How to permanently enable autoplay on Safari?**
- Handle the case with a script and inform your user to allow your website
- Or change your interface.